# Why it is showing multiple or varying frequency?

Tags: matlab, fft

I was expecting the frequency component to be 1700 i.e. a spike at 1700 but the output shows multiple frequency:

```
fs = 44100;
t = 0:1/fs:0.001;
s = sin(2 * pi * 1700 * t);
subplot(211), stem(abs(fft(s))), title('abs(fft(s))')
subplot(212), stem(s), title('s')
```

[image]

Similarly when I tried the below code I did not got what I expected:

```
Fs = 8000;
dt = 1/Fs;           
StopTime = 0.25;        
t = (0:dt:StopTime-dt)'; 
Fc = 60;                    
x = cos(2*pi*Fc*t);
subplot(211), stem(abs(fft(x))), title('abs(fft(x))')
subplot(212), stem(x), title('x')
```

Why my frequency component are being displayed as multiples values as there should be exactly one frequency present in a signal in one steady sine / cos wave.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your signal is not an integer number of cycles there is a discontinuity (remember that the Fourier Transform assumes periodicity), which results in [spectral leakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage), which is visible as a "smearing" of the spectrum. To avoid this we usually apply a suitable [window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) (e.g. [von Hann aka Hanning window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Hann_.28Hanning.29_window))prior to the FFT - think of this as smoothing out the discontinuity. This reduces the smearing and makes peaks more distinct.

As noted in another answer, you also see a second peak because you're plotting the entire spectrum, and every component in the time domain has a positive and a negative frequency component in the frequency domain. For a real-valued signal the FFT is complex-conjugate symmetric in the frequency domain and so half of the spectrum is redundant. You would normally only plot N/2 values.

Comment: I'd say the leakage (smearing) is caused by the signal being of finite duration (time window), rather than by the discontinuity

Comment: @LuisMendo: well it's important to note that you don't get the leakage if the signal is an exact number of cycles, since that makes the discontinuity go away. But of course there is often more than one way of looking at these things.

Comment: It's true that the leakage/smearing is smaller when there is an exact number of cycles. But there is some leakage even in that case. Try the OP first example with `s = sin(2 * pi * 2000 * t);` (two cycles).

Comment: I don't have MATLAB here to try it, but if you're seeing some leakage for an integer no of cycles then I suspect that you haven't got exactly the right number of samples for the input signal - it's easy to be off-by-one when doing this, which introduces a small discontinuity.

Comment: You're right. I had one too many samples. With an integer number of cycles the smearing that exists in the true spectrum (Fourier transform) is hidden by the frequency sampling inherent to the DTF/FFT (all frequency samples fall at zeros of the sinc). Thanks!

Comment: That's a relief - I thought we'd encountered a rift in the space-time continuum! ;-)

Comment: Hahaha I wouldn't say _continuum_. In a continuous spectrum (no frequency sampling) I would have been right, more or less ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It's a single frequency, but it appears twice: positive and negative frequencies. You'll see this better with [`fftshift`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html), which arranges the frequency samples so that they run from -*fs*/2 to *fs*/2:

```
subplot(211)
freq_axis = -fs/2+fs/numel(t):fs/numel(t):fs/2;
stem(freq_axis, abs(fftshift(fft(s))))
title('abs(fft(s))')
```

For example, in your first example this produces the following figure.

[image]

Note the two spikes around +1700 and -1700 Hz. Their location is not exact for two reasons:

- Your time signal is of *finite duration*, which produces convolution with a sinc in the frequency domain. That is, the frequency spike is made wider.
- The FFT gives frequency *samples*, and none of those samples falls exactly at +/-1700 Hz.

In your second example the time signal is longer (it contains more cycles), which reduces the width of the frequency spikes. This can be appreciated in your second figure (again the `fftshift` correction is needed to make the two spikes appear in symmetric frequency locations).

Comment: You're absolutely right. Just to add - your frequency axis is essentially `(0:1/T:(N-1)/T)` (when not using `fftshift`), with `N` the number of samples and `T` the length in time. Which reads easily that if `T` increases, the frequency resolution (around the frequency of interest) increases, as you already pointed out. Also, only frequencies that appear in that axis will be shown without leakage.